# function to calculate function fps

Tags: javascript, frame-rate

Ok so I believe I could best describe the issue through code so here goes

```js
var clicks = 0;

//function to calculate
function clicking(){
  clicks += 1;
}

//function to calculate fps where fn is the name of the function
function FPS(fn){
  //do stuff
}
```

Okay so to clarify I dont want to add a variable to the actual function `clicking` I would like to be able to call something like
`FPS(clicking)` and have the function return a value for example

```js
var fps = FPS(clicking);
```

then i could display the returned number as such
`element.innerHTML = fps`

**EDIT:**
I know with the current code it seems silly but this is just example coding not what I am actually using

Comment: What is "FPS" when applied to a function?

Comment: fps is basically how fast the function runs

Comment: So you want a stopwatch? e.g. call `startClock(); fn(); stopClock();` and calculate the delta?

Comment: well the purppose of it is to be able to tell if the game is lagging

Comment: Does your game have an elapsed time since last frame was drawn?

Comment: Then it's very hard to give you an answer with such little information about the specifics to your game.  If you just want to see how fast the function is running, you get the time before and after the function call and calculate the difference.  Then you accumulate the differences until they are greater than 1 second and count how many times that function called.

Comment: the specifics of my game are irrelevant in the matter because i plan to use the function on multiple functions as a method of debugging as well as display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not very actual since `Date.now()` also uses time.

```js
function FPS(fn) {
  var startTime = Date.now();
  fn();
  var endTime = Date.now();

  return endTime - startTime;
}

function longClick() {
  var abc = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    abc++;
  }
}

var fps = FPS(longClick);
console.log((fps / 1000) + ' seconds');
```

---

*FPS* usually refers to *Frames Per Second* which is the frequency of refreshing screen image.

Pick a more comprehensive name, with keywords like *Elapsed*, for teammates.

Comment: It is because your `clicking` is so simple that it is completed within one millisecond. Such simple functions are counted in 1/1000 milliseconds.

Comment: ran function dett(i){while(i > 0){i--}} where i = 10 and still returns 0

Comment: Your computer can calculate millions of addition per second. 10 is just nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question:

> Okay so to clarify I dont want to add a variable to the actual function clicking I would like to be able to call something like FPS(clicking) and have the function return a value for example

Firstly you need to return a value from your `clicking` function, or any function you plan to pass to the `FPS` method.

```
var clicks = 0;

//function to calculate
function clicking(){
    clicks += 1;
    return clicks;
}
```

Then in your `FPS` function, you need to return that value as well.

```
//function to calculate fps where fn is the name of the function
function FPS(fn){
    //do stuff
    return fn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know "how fast the functions runs" :

```js
/**
 * Return the execution time of a function
 * @param {Function} fn The function to execute
 */
function FPS(fn) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  fn();
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  return end - start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code to get what I think you're looking for - assuming you have a game loop and you're calling FPS in your game loop.  As I said - more details about the specifics (such as components) of your game would be helpful.

```
var clicks = 0;
var fps = 0;
var elapsedTime;

//function to calculate
function clicking(){
  clicks += 1;
}

//function to calculate fps where fn is the name of the function
function FPS(fn){
  // Get start time
  //call fn
  // Get stop time
  // var delta = stop time - start time
  // elapsedTime += delta;
  // fps++;
  // If elapsedTime > 1 second 
  // then while elapsedTime > 1 second... elapsedTime -= 1 second and fps = 0;
  // We use the while loop here in the event that it took more than 1 second in the call
  // But you could just reset elapsedTime back to 0
}
```

This FPS(fn) would be called anywhere in your game in place of the original function to see how many times that function is called a second.

Answer (score 0):

You can have FPS return a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) (works in IE 10+, Firefox 15+, Chrome 20+, Safari 8+) which will return time in milliseconds. If you want it to work in older browser you can replace the precision timing with a Date (`new Date()`) object but the Date object will only nab you time in seconds (not milliseconds):

```
var clicks = 0;

//function to calculate
function clicking(){
  clicks += 1;
}

//function to calculate fps where fn is the name of the function
function FPS(fn){
  var start = performance.now();
  fn();
  return performance.now() - start;
}

console.log("Function took " + FPS(clicking) + " milliseconds!");
```